# How to "arrange" aggregate variable in dbplyr?

Tags: r, dbplyr

The following dbplyr statement fails:

```
foo <- activity_viewed %>% group_by(pk) %>% summarize(total = n()) %>%
  arrange(-total) %>% head(3) %>% collect()
```

with this error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "total" does not exist
LINE 4: ORDER BY -"total"
                  ^
)
```

I can see the problem in the query: SQL doesn't allow the `ORDER BY` to use column aliases.

Here's the generated query:

```
> print(show_query(foo))
<SQL>
SELECT "pk", COUNT(*) AS "total"
FROM "activity"
GROUP BY "pk"
ORDER BY -"total"
LIMIT 3
```

I need `ORDER BY -COUNT(*)`.

How do I get `dbplyr` to execute this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbplyr` can translate `desc` but not `-`

```
library(dplyr) 
library(dbplyr) 
mtcars2 <- src_memdb() %>% 
           copy_to(mtcars, name = "mtcars2-cc", overwrite = TRUE)
mtcars2 %>% arrange(desc(cyl)) %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `mtcars2-cc`
ORDER BY `cyl` DESC
```